# Show that $\prod_{d|n}\Phi_{d}(x)=(x^{n}-1)$

Tags: number-theory

Define for $n \geq 1$

$\Phi_{n}(x)=\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ gcd(k,n)=1}}(x-e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}})$.

Show that $\prod_{d|n}\Phi_{d}(x)=(x^{n}-1)$

Comment: I have tried reasoning with sets but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Don't reason with sets, reason with zeros (of the polynomials).

Comment: For $(x^{n}-1)=0$ we get roots $e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}$ for $k=1,2,...,n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, sets of zeros...

Comment: @anon Point. ${}{}$

Comment: A little more help would be useful.

Comment: do you see this could be true by considering simple cases $n=3$ and $n=4$ just to get some flavor... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$\mathbb N_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
and 
$$A_d=\{k\in \mathbb N_n\;|\; \gcd(k,n)=d\}$$

**Hint**

Prove that $(A_d)_{d|n}$ is a partition of $\mathbb N_n$ and then

$$(x^n-1)=\prod_{k\in \mathbb N_n}(x-e^{2ik\pi/n})=\prod_{d|n}\prod_{k\in A_d}(x-e^{2ik\pi/n})$$
finally notice that $$k\in A_d\iff\gcd(k,n)=d\\\iff \gcd(k/d=k',n/d=d')=1\iff k'\in\{k\in \mathbb N_n\;|\; \gcd(k,d)=1\}$$